# Variables is not inherited?

Tags: dart

Please consider following code:

```dart
abstract class ClassAbstract {
    static int _someValue = 10;

    ClassAbstract() {}   
  }

  class NormalClass extends ClassAbstract {
    NormalClass(): super() {}

    void RunMe() {
      print("Value from abstract super: $_someValue");  // Error here
    }
  }


  void main() {
    NormalClass normalClass = new NormalClass();
    normalClass.RunMe();
    print("Application close");
  }
```

When I run this I receive an error:

```dart
Class 'NormalClass' has no instance getter '_someValue@0x213da713'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '_someValue@0x213da713'
Receiver: Instance of 'NormalClass'
Arguments: []
```

Maybe I mistaken here but global, static variables must be inherited  but as can see from this example it does not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static members are indeed *not* inherited in Dart. If you want to access them outside of their declaring class, you always have to qualify the access with the class name.

In your case:

```dart
class NormalClass extends ClassAbstract {
  void runMe() {
    print("Value from abstract super: ${ClassAbstract._someValue}");
  }
}
```

The specification has a few words to say about this in chapter 7.7 (a non-normative part):

> Inheritance of static methods has little utility in Dart. Static methods cannot be overridden. Any required static function can be obtained from its declaring library, and there is no need to bring it into scope via inheritance. Experience shows that developers are confused by the idea of inherited methods that are not instance methods.
>
> Of course, the entire notion of static methods is debatable, but it is retained here because so many programmers are familiar with it. Dart static methods may be seen as functions of the enclosing library.